# NSSNotifiaction integration for iAD in project

Tags: iphone, iad, nsnotificationcenter

I have tabbed application and i like to  present `iAd` on each view at different position according to space availability , so i thought of add functionality of `iAd` in app delegate and create its instance and use it according to requirement , so for message passing between different tabbed app and view i like to use `NSNotificationCenter` , but its not calling the assign method, here is my code

```
     //this appdelegte.m


    - (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        BOOL yy=    self.bannerView.bannerLoaded;
        if (yy==1)
        {  
            self.iAdString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1"];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BannerViewActionWillBegin" object:self];

        }

        else

        {
             self.iAdString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"0"];

        }


    }

    - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
          postNotificationName:@"BannerViewActionDidFinish" object:self];

            [self layoutAnimated:YES];
   }

     //and i call this nsnotification in VieController.m like this


    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 

    {


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:@"BannerViewActionWillBegin "object:nil];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:) name:@"BannerViewActionDidFinish" object:nil];


     - (void)willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification


    {

        [self.view addSubview:self.app.bannerView];



    }



    - (void)didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
         NSLog(@"come");
        [self.app.bannerView removeFromSuperview];
     }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether this method is execute are not "didFailToReceiveAdWithError "?

Comment: any good suggestion please, wannna to show iAd in all viewsbut differnt places in tabbed app, please guide me flow of this at least what way i should chose to acheive this,

Comment: nsnotificattion method in viewwill appear not calling assign method to it, when every nsnotifiaction in app delegate getting notice

Comment: Is This case will appear BOOL yy=    self.bannerView.bannerLoaded;
        if (yy==1)?

Comment: yes but, same notifiaction not trigerring in any view controller, where shoul i call nsnotifiaction any standard way to call it up